# Grunt generates empty file from typescript source

Tags: javascript, typescript, gruntjs

I am using grunt to compile typescripts and generate some .js files from these. Problem is, for some reason I always get empty file in which is only one line - reference from compiled file. But is should contain quite complex javascript module.

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({

        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON("package.json"),

        clean: {
            dist: { src: ["dist"], force: true }
        },

        copy: {

        },

        typescript: {
            base: {
                src: [
                    "AwesomeGrid/**/*.ts"
                ],
                //dest: "dist/grid-fp.js",
                dest: "dist",
                options: {
                    target: "es5"
                }
            }
        }
    });

    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-contrib-clean");
    grunt.loadNpmTasks("grunt-typescript");

    grunt.registerTask("default", ["clean", "typescript:base"]);
};
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "FalsePositiveManagement",
  "version": "2.0.0-alpha",
  "private": true,
  "author": "Moravia s.r.o.",
  "license": "none",
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "~0.6.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-typescript": "^0.8.0"
  }
}
```

source .ts file:

```
    ///<reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>

    module Fp {
        export interface IGroupSettings {
            key: string;
            title: string;
            icon: string;
            url: string;
            active: boolean;
        }

        export interface IFPGridTableSettings {
            tableElement: JQuery;
            gridOptions: AwesomeGrid.IGridOptions;
        }
```

generated .js file:

```
///<reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
```

tsd.d.ts file:

```
    /// <reference path="jquery/jquery.d.ts" />

    /// <reference path="bootstrap/bootstrap.d.ts" />

    /// <reference path="chance/chance.d.ts" />

    /// <reference path="moment/moment.d.ts" />

    /// <reference path="grid/grid.d.ts" />

    /// <reference path="jasmine/jasmine.d.ts"/>
```

I am quite new to this, but it suppose grunt should take code from referenced files and compile it into target .js file, but it doesn't. It just generates files with reference rows...

Comment: Interfaces in Typescript are not compiled into JS code due to absence of corresponding JS code constructions. From this TS code you can get ".d.ts" files - typescript definitions. Vars, functions, classes will produce some JS code.

Comment: @TSV - yeah, you are right, I began with typescript and grunt yesterday and obviously got it wrong way, thanks a lot. Make an answer and I will mark it.

Comment: glad to help you :) I've made an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interfaces in Typescript are not compiled into JS code due to absence of corresponding JS code constructions.

From given TS code (interface declarations) you can get ".d.ts" files only - typescript definitions.

Vars, functions, classes will produce some JS code.